# How do I access a nested value inside this JSON object?

Tags: json, bitcoin

```
{
"payload": "{\"apiVersion\":\"0.1.0\",\"timestamp\":\"2020-07-12T18:04:45.901Z\",\"returnResult\":\"success\",\"resultDescription\":\"\",\"blockHash\":\"00000000000000000096b13c9aee9b1a0b02daecf8200a10616adf1349eefd4f\",\"blockHeight\":641659,\"confirmations\":1723,\"minerId\":\"03e92d3e5c3f7bd945dfbf48e7a99393b1bfb3f11f380ae30d286e7ff2aec5a270\",\"txSecondMempoolExpiry\":0}",
"signature": "3045022100cf2a2e272ae02e95a37dc010342d759714a22c1bda9761807049f46ce3962f14022074e70938e06ac8095498007f1e4a84373226c2928b7d26d97b337d6328b59c0c",
"publicKey": "03e92d3e5c3f7bd945dfbf48e7a99393b1bfb3f11f380ae30d286e7ff2aec5a270",
"encoding": "UTF-8",
"mimetype": "application/json" }
```

I am currently working on a project using Javascript. In my logic, I make a fetch, which posts transaction data to an MAPI, which returns the JSON object listed above. I am trying to access a particular value inside the 'payload' key. For the sake of this question - Can we access the timestamp value?

I would then like to save this value to a variable, so that I can use it for another task.

My code:

```
async function postData(url ='', data = { }) {
    
    const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) });
    let txoData = await response.json();
    let timestamp = Object.values(Object.values(txoData)[0]['timestamp'])

    return txoData;
}

postData('https://merchantapi.taal.com/mapi/tx', { 'rawtx': raw1 })
.then(txoData => { console.log(txoData) })
.then(timestamp => { console.log(timestamp) })`
```

My previous code returned "undefined"

Comment: You need a clear question to get a clear answer :) You didn't even specify a programming language..

Comment: SO is about working with what you've tried. Please edit your post to show your work so we can help you through it.

Comment: what have you tried and what is the error? something like object.payload.timestamp should work, can you post the existing code that does not work?

Comment: I apologise, very new to overflow. will edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.json() returns the json object, which means the the string data is available as object so object notation can be used to read values using appropriate nested property names.

so, below should work

```
let txoData = await response.json();
let timestamp = txoData.payload.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the json object (response.json()) you can access properties by knowing the name of the properties in the following ways:

```
var a = jsonObj.propertyName;
```

Or in this way:

```
var a = jsonObj['propertyName'];
```